# Where to store Sodium Azide?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, safety

I have about 100g of Sodium azide and would like to store it properly. Any suggestions as to where? I though of storing it in a locked vault but there are chemicals such as Arsenic sulfide, aniline, and Potassium cyanide, but the presence of metals in the cabinet makes me a bit queezy.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the MSDS of the hazardous materials, which you are planning to store together. At least in Germany, these materials are assigned to storage classes (in German: *Lagerklasse (LGK)*).

The German regulations are to be found in the document **TRGS 510**, TRGS stands for *Technische Regeln für Gefahrstoffe* (Technical Regulations for Hazardous Materials). Document 510 of this series specifies *Lagerung von Gefahrstoffen in ortsbeweglichen Behältern* ([Storage of hazardous materials in non-stationary containers](http://www.baua.de/en/Topics-from-A-to-Z/Hazardous-Substances/TRGS/TRGS-510.html)). Within **TRGS 510**, you'll find a "compatibility table" that specifies, which storage classes may (not) be stored together.

Sodium azide belongs to the *LGK 6.1 A* (flammable , acute toxic hazardous materials of category 1 and 2).

Materials from *LGK 6.1 A* may be stored together with other materials of the same *LGK*, but not, for example, with explosives (*LGK 1*), strong oxidants (*LGK 5.1 A), organic peroxides (*LGK 5.2), pyrophororic materials (*LGK 4.2), etc.