# Oxidizers Cabinet

Tags: safety

I am currently reorganizing the chemical inventory in our lab and grouped all the oxidizers together. Would it be safe to put the following chemicals together in the fume hood cabinet? I have checked the SDS for any incompatibilities/storage and everything seems to be in the clear.

Oxidizers Cabinet

Sodium chlorate
Potassium dichromate
Sodium dichromate
Potassium permanganate
Potassium persulfate
Aluminum nitrate
Ferric nitrate
Magnesium nitrate
Nickel nitrate
Sodium nitrate
Silver nitrate
Strontium nitrate
Potassium nitrite
Sodium nitrite
Sodium cobalt nitrite
Sodium peroxide

Thanks in advance,

C

Comment: Sodium chlorate tics me a bit. It is highly hygroscopic, but if dry it may produce nasty mixtures with most organics of any sort and many nonorganics. Persulfate has low active oxygen content and probably may be moved to a less secure location.

Answer (score 4):

As with your [previous question on azides](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/46547/where-to-store-sodium-azide), the same regulation on storage classes (*LGK*), namely **TRGS 510**, applies.

You neither seem to have ammonium nitrate (LGK 5.1C), nor organic peroxides (LGK 5.2).

**If your oxidants belong to the storage classes *5.1A* and *5.1B*, you may store them together.**